# Benefits of Separating Home Directory?

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, home-directory

I'm trying to strategize my ubuntu installation. I've always read that separating the /home directory makes it easier when it comes to upgrading your distro. But could somebody please explain why? I'm trying to determine if it would be worth it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason used to be so that you can format `/` and not format `/home`. Nowadays it does not matter any more: the installer lets you keep your `/home`.

There are still a few good reasons:

- if `/` gets full over something like 95% the filesystem starts to store parts of files not together (ie. defragmentation) so performance will take a small hit.

  When `/` is 100% full you will have a harder time logging it due to the system not being able to use the free space effectively.

  So a separate `/home` where you store your personal data will keep your `/` as empty as possible unless you have a server (apache, mailserver and mysql store their userdata by default in `/var`).
- A separate `/home` also allows for encryption of just that partition.
- If `/home` is on an actual different hard disc you can pull it out and put into another system that holds a `/` and use that.

---

In that respect depending on your needs and what your system is used for it might be better to create a separate `/data` partition, have `/var/www/html` symlink to `/data/var/www/html` so your websites are on the data disk, change the default database location for `mysql` to point to `/data/var/mysql/` and symlink your `/home/$USER/` directories (aka. Desktop, etc). to `/data/home/{dirs}`.

If `/data` is an actual disk you could take it out of your system, place it into an upgraded Ubuntu and continue working on it. Besides maybe a little snag here and there (like settings that got removed from `mysql` or `apache`) you could have a new system with all your data up and running in a single reboot and the time it takes to insert the disk into that new machine.

I do that a lot with my notebooks.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your insightful answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have a separate `/home` partition for general use on a desktop system.

This is a kind of "tradition" to have it as a separate partition. There is almost no difference when you re-install.

The reasons to have it separate are, but not limited to:

1. Having an encrypted Home.
2. Using LVM.
3. Having a different file system, like XFS for Home.

There may be other reasons that I cannot recall right now.

But if you already have installed with `/home` on the same partition as `/`, it is not worth the effort to change it anyway.

Disadvantage of having it separate is that you will always have to waste some space on your `/`.

But as a bottom line I can say that there is almost no difference.