# Can`t see HDD disk after Ubuntu 18.04 install on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I am new user to Ubuntu. I used Windows last 10 years. Excuse me for stupid questions and for bad English.

I bought a new Acer Aspire 3 laptop - 4 GB of RAM, 128 SSD drive and 500 GB HDD drive.

I decided to put Ubuntu. I recorded the ISO image on a USB flash drive, booted, everything was as usual.

During installation, select "Erase Windows and install automatically".

Those whole installation took place automatically, without my participation.

Now I look, my root partition (/ or /home) has 128 GB. This is my SSD drive.

I can’t find my HDD drive anywhere. Ubuntu does not see him.

Please tell me, how can I get my HDD disk now?

I will store all of my user files (such as videos, documents and work files) on the HDD disk.

And SSD disk for only system files.

Comment: Open the app called disks and see if it appears there. If so, update the question.

Comment: Thank you sir for answer! I go to disks and see my HDD disk.

I created a 500 GB drive and it is located in the media/user1 folder. This is normal? In the future, should I should save my folders here?

Comment: No. You should save your folders in your /home directory. Then tell the system to keep your /home dir on the HDD instead of SSD using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving . You can see that the relationship between disk and filesystem is quite different on Linux - you must learn the Linux way or you will be frustrated.

Comment: Thank you sir for answers! Please, let me question again. 

Why I should move /home directory into HDD disk? Different programs was been  installed in the / home directory.

And will they run faster from the SSD?

And will I place user files on the HDD? Excuse me until I understood and got confused.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/661165/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-c-drive-on-ssd-and-d-drive-on-hdd

Answer (score 0):

It would take me some time to explain step by step how to do this. However you might want to watch [this video](https://youtu.be/AeR8Rk5LwWU?t=298) as it helped me setting up my hdd as well. Just note that he is creating two partition on his hdd but this is kinda useless. Just create one big partition on it. If there is already a partition on the hdd then format it to ext4 as shown.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much for link! I go to now and watch it. Please, let me question. What, If I /home directory put into my HDD? And / (root directory) into SSD? Its will bee, like on Windows (local disk C for SSD and system files and local disk D for HDD with user files).

Comment: @Alex, we try to limit the scope of questions to one issue per question here. May I suggest you create a new question to ask that question, if https://askubuntu.com/questions/661165/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-c-drive-on-ssd-and-d-drive-on-hdd dos not answer it sufficiently?